# SharePoint Gantt View: "ListViewWebPart" error, comes up when I change from default view to Gantt

Tags: sharepoint, ms-project, gantt-chart

I have linked a microsoft project plan 2010 to SharePoint 2010 and am able to edit and add tasks when it is in a normal table view.  However, when I go to create view and attempt to display it as a gantt, then I get "ListViewWebPart" error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values."  I don't know how to fix this.